# How do I create a FAQ or Help page?

Tags: discussion, support

An easy way to test certain theories about improving Code Review's demographics would be to run ads on Stack Overflow.

I ask because I would like to form an opinion for myself about how hard it is to add FAQs. A *specific* answer to this question will allow me this.

A "where should I ask?" FAQ with a list of other Stack Exchange sites to which Code Review questions not on-topic could be migrated would be a good idea.

Can just anyone make a Help page or an FAQ page?

Comment: What is with the `// ,`? I don't think that amounts to any kind of allowed markdown on SE... Good question otherwise though.

Comment: How is the *Code Review's demographics* and running ads on Stack Overflow related to the rest of the question, which seems to be about adding a FAQ or Help page?

Comment: // , It puts the focus an actual problem I have faced. This way I can, if need be, include details about what I have tried and exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: // , @Phrancis If it's a good question, upvote. As to the "  // , ", it 's sort of a long story.

Comment: // , ok... hope you get good answers...

Answer (score 10):

You can ask any question on Meta.  If the community deems it to be an important question, then a moderator will add an [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag on it.

Recently, we have also been starting to promote the most important information from Meta [into Help Center](/q/5086/9357).